# Jquery Field Validation onblur (mvc)

Tags: jquery, html, validation, html-helper

I want to have the fields in my form be validated after the user clicks out of them. However, I am not familiar with client side validation using Jquery. Can anyone explain how to validate that the field is not empty?

```
<label id="lblAccountName">Account Name</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.AccountName, new { @id = "txtAccountName", @Name = "txtAccountName" })
```

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials, in particular [Adding Validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with JS

```
var accName = document.getElementById('txtAccountName');
accName.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    if (accName.value != "") {
        //do something
    }
});
```

**Updated**
Or in jQuery:

```
var accName = $("#txtAccountName");
accName.blur(function () {
    if (accName.val() != "") {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks for giving me both solutions as well!