# positioning of validation message for mvc form field

Tags: jquery, html, validation, razor, html.beginform

I have client-side validation applied to the fields in my form so that they don't remain empty. However, the message shows up underneath the input fields. How can i make it so that they show up next to the field?

form field:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAccount", "RxCard", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "save", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{              
  <label id="lblAccountName">Account Name</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.AccountName, new { @id = "txtAccountName", @Name = "txtAccountName", required = "required" })
  ...
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#save').validate({
        onchange: function (element) {
            this.element(element);
            console.log('onchange fired');
        },
        onfocusout: function (element) {
            this.element(element);
            console.log('onfocusout fired');
        }
    });

});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your using HTML-5 validation which is controller by your browser. Use MVC's inbuilt validation features (using validation attributes and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`) to get both client and server side validation and allow you to position/style the message. Side note: never attempt to override the `name` attribute using `@Name = "txtAccountName"` - it guarantees that model binding will fail

Comment: Which css you are using for design?

Comment: @StephenMuecke the thing is that i need validation to occur on an onchange event. That is why I'm not using the validation attributes in my model. Is there a way to tweak the validation message for to occur onchange?

Comment: That is exactly what MVC's client side validation will do (and far more) - read my comment on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379945/jquery-field-validation-onblur-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MVC's Inbuilt Modelstate Validation's like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAccount(Account account)
{
    // It's return true when AccountName have some value, return false if it's NULL
   if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
   {
       // Return to the page with the Validation errorsMessages.
       return View();
   }
  return RedirectToAction("YOUR VIEW NAME");
}
```

**Your Class**

```
public Class Account
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "AccountName is required")]
   public string AccountName { get; set; }
}
```

**Chtml Page**

```
// I am using bootstrap for Showing your error Next to the Textbox
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAccount", "RxCard", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "save", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span3">
      <label id="lblAccountName">Account Name</label>
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AccountName, new { @id = "txtAccountName", @Name = "txtAccountName", required = "required" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountName, "", new { @id = "accountID", @class = "text-danger", style = "color:red;" })
   </div>
 </div>
}
```

> UPDATE

You can add a Simple `onChange` or `blur` event on the Textbox to a validation on `client side.`, Just assign a `ID` to the `ValidationMessageFor` as i add above.

```
$("#AccountName").change(function ()
 {
     // change this with your own condition..
     if ($("#AccountName").val() != 0)
     {
         $("#accountID").text("This field is not correct");
         $("#accountID").attr('class', 'field-validation-error');
     }
 });
```

You can also use your Server Side validations with this `JQuery event`.

Learn More about [Using Data Annotations for Model Validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6)

Comment: I would definitely take this approach but can I modify the validation so that it occurs on an onchange event? I need validation to occur after the user exits the field.

Comment: Great! This is what i needed. Thank you sir.